# How to implement REST with APEX call in native Android apps?

Tags: android, salesforce, apex-code, apex, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am trying to execute the apex request using http method `GET` and passing some parameters and getting response as "OK" in result from backend.
On success, I get the mail of an document in pdf format on my email address.
But the problem is that the pdf is not opening from my mail.

I am not able to open the email received on executing the apex request from the android app.

I always get the message "PDF IS IN INVALID FORMAT".

But this request from ios app works.

Any clue why this is happening ?
Is this the issue of frontend ?

FYI : This is the request

`GET /services/apexrest/emailResumePDF?pdfId=a1C0P000006BwwOUAS&emailAddress=ritunagpal%40gmail.com`

Comment: Please, add more details about REST endpoint and add server logs